# Is it possible to go to a path shown in my JSON with a click

Tags: node.js, json, visual-studio-code

Consider a `JSON` file that looks like this :

```
{
"1651984021690": "log\\extended\\1651984021690.json"
}
```

the path you see is a real path, relative to the root of the program, is it possible to go to this path using something like a `ctrl + click` and open this file?.
I'm using `vs code` and I'm fine with using any kind of `package` or `extension` or anything else that might help me achieve this.

Comment: I managed to file a solution , I noticed vs code allows you to click on links in JSON files so I changed my log path so its a link to a file in PC something like this file://log//extended//1651984021690.json, this allowed me to just click on the link and go the file but I'm getting an error which says `unable to open the file`, i think its because it doesn't understand relative path ?,

Comment: have you tried using `file://./log/extended/1651984021690.json`, do not use `//` as dir separator and use `./` for relative file

Comment: @rioV8 Still doesn't work, I'm questioning if its even possible to do this using relative path.., I really liked to avoid using absolute path, by the way here is the error : `Unable to write file '\\.\log\extended\1651984021690.json' (EntryNotFound (FileSystemError): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '\\.\log\extended')`